# What is the definition of nodal singularity of an algebraic curve?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

What is the definition of nodal singularity of an algebraic curve  ?

I got the following definition from [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/nodal+curve):

> A nodal singularity of an algebraic curve is one of the forms parameterized by the equation $xy=0$. A nodal curve is a curve with a nodal singularity.

Apparently, it is not clear to me the parametrization $xy=0$.

Can you please explain it?

Comment: Some related references may be found in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3418603/multiplicative-reduction-of-a-elliptic-curve-e-splits). Specifically, [Vakil](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf) discusses this in section 29.3 of The Rising Sea, and Stacks Project discusses this at [tag 0C46](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0C46).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the completion of the local ring at the point is isomorphic to $k[[x, y]]/(xy)$. Intuitively, if you zoom way in it looks like the letter $X$ at the bad point.

Comment: So, If we consider an algebraic curve in $n$-variables $x_1,~x_2,~,\cdots,x_n$, then the completion of the local ring at the nodal point is isomorphic to  the ring $K[[x_1,~x_2, \cdots, x_n]]/(x_1x_2 \cdots x_n)$. Is it ?

Comment: @mathvision since it's a curve, it should be one-dimensional, so the isomorphism class is always $k[[x, y]]/(xy)$ (the number of variables in the completion is just two, regardless of the dimension of the ambient space in which the curve is cut out).